# How to declare variables in DUST?

Tags: node.js, dust.js

I have a javascript code to declare a variable. i need a way to do the same in DUST??

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
          String flag = "ON";
    </script>

how to do this DUST???
```

Comment: That's not JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Dust is logicless template, so can't use logic like javascript. But if you want to using a variable as a flag, and you are using partials, you can add like this 
{>partials flag='ON' /}
And in that partials you can use that variable.

Answer (score 0):

Dust templates are meant to be logicless, so there would be no adding new variables from inside it. Ofcourse you can add properties to the object you pass to be rendered as variables.